# unknown host exception in connecting to sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, tcp

```
try
{

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
System.out.println("connected successfully");


Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://server  name/dbname","username","password"); 


Statement statement = con.createStatement() ; 

ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select FileName_WO_Ext  from dbo.ALLOTMENT WHERE STR_TO_DATE(DATE, '%d/%m/%Y') >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND STR_TO_DATE(DATE, '%d/%m/%Y') <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);") ;


while(resultset.next())
{
String datee =resultset.getString("FileName_WO_Ext ");
 out.println(datee);
}
}
catch(SQLException ex){
System.out.println("exception--"+ex);

}
```

first when i had error on the tcp/ip connection to the host i have done the following steps upto

-Configure TCP/IP communication with SQL Express

-Open SQL Server Configuration Manager.

-Go to SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS

-Set the status of TCP/IP protocol to "Enabled" (if it is already not).

-Open Properties window for TCP/IP, go to IP Addresses section.

-Go to the bottom of this property page and set the TCP Port under IPAll to 1433.

but still i am getting the exception

---com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed. java.net.UnknownHostException:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the syntax of con should be like

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://server name;databaseName=your database name","username","password");

by giving this syntax my error was removed

Answer (score 0):

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://server  name/dbname","username","password");

the connection details should be proper.

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433 name/test","username","password");
```

Specify the user name and respective passwords